# Creating new database object on DBeaver - ERROR: permission denied to create database

Tags: dbeaver

Probably basic stuff.  I'm just trying out DBeaver for the first time to set up a Postgresql database.

1. I chose new database connection - Postgres
2. Host: localhost
   Database: postgres
   Username: postgres and system password ... All connected

but when I right click create new database or schema I get the error

"SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied to create database
ERROR: permission denied to create database"

Where could I be doing wrong?

[image: screen_shot]

Answer (score 1):

User `postgres` don't have `Create Database` permission.

You can check list of given permissions from `Roles->postgres`

[image]

Note: By default `Super User` will have all the permissions but if your's is not `Super User` then you have to establish connection using `Super User` and then enable required permissions to `Non Super User`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu OS. In my case was an issue when trying to save a DUMP on SSD. I solved by following steps:

```
1st - open ubuntu software
2nd - search for dbeaver-ce
3rd - after installed it, click Permissions
4th - check Read/write files on removable storage devices
```

Hope it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried to create a database. In my case, the issue was in my connection created in the DBeaver. I had a database name specified in my connection in DBeaver. So my connection becomes ready-only. That means my database connection was specific to the given database. So I created a new connection with the default settings without choosing a database[image].

Answer (score -2):

I tried to do the same over several hours yesterday. Apparently, DBeaver doesn't allow the creation of new databases (at least at this version of the software). You can connect to an existing DB and that's about it.

Comment: You should read the dbeaver documentation.  You can almost to everything from the dbeaver interface...